# Converting couple of shell scripts to Java Batch application

Tags: java, shell, spring-batch

I have 4 to 5 shell scripts that i need to convert into batch application so that it can be automated.
The shell scripts basically are on the basis of the following snippet.

java -cp Proj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.proj.xxx.ClassName

I want to convert these shell scripts into batch application.I am using the Reader Writer Proccesor way for the java batch application. Can some help me on how to do it?

Comment: Cool, good luck with that. Thanks for sharing. Do you have a question?

Comment: I see your edit. That was way too broad, you need to try this yourself first and come back when you have a specific question about code you've written.

Comment: I don't know where to start. I have the program written and manually using the shell scripts it runs fine, I am just stuck on making it automatic i.e making it a batch application

Comment: @UnknownOctopus - Please do not refer off-topic questions like this to Programmers.  This question would be quickly closed and likely down voted on Programmers.  Have a read of http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow to see what's on-topic for Programmers.

Comment: @GlenH7 Noted, thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want to do makes more sense to do in apache ant (http://ant.apache.org).